# Grammar error in Review

Tags: bug

FYI, I noticed this on ELL this morning, and it shows up here as well:

[image: This question doesn't meet a [sic] English Language & Usage Stack Exchange guideline.]

> This question doesn't meet a [sic] English Language & Usage Stack Exchange guideline.

[Eddie Kal has posted on Meta SE about it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/354233/grammar-error-in-review-does-this-affect-several-se-sites).

Comment: I'm guessing it's going to be hard to code "does the next word start with a vowel sound". But perhaps it's per-site modifiable.

Comment: The current recommendation is to change it to "This question doesn't meet [site name] guidelines".

Comment: That makes sense.

Comment: Quick, efficient, and preventing a great deal of embarrassment.

Comment: Another option would be to change from "a ... guideline" to "one or more ... guidelines." That version would sound better if "doesn't" were changed to "fails to" earlier in the sentence.

Comment: @MattE.Эллен If you think that it might be “hard
to code ‘Does the next word start with a vowel
sound?’ ”, then you may well be delightfully surprised albeït
mayhap unastonished to learn of [this already coded
solution](https://metacpan.org/pod/Lingua::EN::Inflexion#indef_article())
at one’s disposal, along with its [underlying
implementation](https://metacpan.org/release/Lingua-EN-Inflexion/source/lib/Lingua/EN/Inflexion/Indefinite.pm), …

Comment: @MattE.Эллен … not to mention [its historical
precursor](https://metacpan.org/pod/Lingua::EN::Inflect#PROVIDING-INDEFINITE-ARTICLES)
along with [its own respective
implementation](https://metacpan.org/release/Lingua-EN-Inflect/source/lib/Lingua/EN/Inflect.pm#L1346).
My point is that in programming communities where a premium is placed on 
**ɴᴏᴛ** generating ungrammatical nonsense by careless programmers deaf 
to the intricacies and exigencies of English morphophonology, pre-packaged
solutions are readily available in plenty—the contrapositive of which
is also lamentably true.

Comment: @tchrist that's surprising, and pleasing. When I get the chance I'll take a look to see how it's done.

Comment: Shows how much people actually read those banners!

Comment: @tchrist Ah, Perl. Those were happy days... *Gazes dreamily into the distance* / *Notices a certain cookbook on the shelf*

Comment: This problem still exists as of 2 Jan 2021, even though it was first posted on Meta SE back in June 2020. I've therefore posted a follow-up question [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359044).

Comment: Not fixed as of 1 Mar 2021. And the link in the commment above gives a 404.

Comment: Eight months now. Welcome to the site for "linguists, etymologists, and (serious) English language enthusiasts."

Comment: The original bug report is one year old today. This bug still has not been corrected. https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/349877/349502

Answer (score 1):

**It's STILL not fixed**, but I did get the necromancer badge on meta.stackexchange.com for bumping it.

[image: Recent Achievements]